# Resources getting shared on different networks

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6

I have developed a web application where we can sign into to once dropbox account and get their data. 
The problem here is ,lets say user(X) accessed the web application through a browser and sign into his dropbox account in the network (lets say A) , now if we open the same web application in another network (lets say B) it also says that the user (X) has signed into the dropbox account.

Same happens between browsers also, Like if a user (X) opened the application in google chrome and signed into the dropbox account and when the user opens the application in Mozilla it says that user(X) has signed in.

The application is developed in Java using Spring MVC framework, used jsp pages for UI and jquery.
Im running this application on Apache Tomcat Server.

Question:
How do I make resources not shared among browsers and networks.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing how you actually implemented authentication. There's clearly a bug there, very likely a fundamental design flaw.

Comment: @kryger - There are apis given by dropbox for getting the access token(signing in) and disabling the access token (signing out).
https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-authorize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to implement sessions in the project and store the accesstoken given by Dropbox as part of Outh 2.0 protocol as a session variable.
Whenever the user tries to request the web-application, that particular session loads up and uses the value of accesstoken present in that session variable.

In this way we can differentiate between requests.